# c# Interface type of Memory cards using Win32_DiskDrive object

Tags: c#, properties, disk

I need to identify all drives and all logical partitions of each drive and I am having really troubles while dealing with memory cards (integrated reader in the laptop).

I am using this code

```
        void GetFullInfoDiskDrives()
    {
        Global.LogMessage("************** GetFullInfoDiskDrives() Getting complete info from all disk drives ", 1);
        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
            new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive");

        foreach (ManagementObject info in searcher.Get())
        {
            // Lets print all the properties per disk
            PropertyDataCollection properties = info.Properties;
            // display the properties
            Global.LogMessage("-----------------   Properties for the disk " + info["Model"].ToString(),1);

            foreach (PropertyData property in properties)
            {
                Global.LogMessage("[" + property.Name + "] = '" + property.Value +"'", 1);
                foreach (QualifierData q in property.Qualifiers)
                {
                    Global.LogMessage("       -" + q.Name + "- = '" + q.Value + "'", 1);
                }
            }
            string s = "";
            string s_model = info["Model"].ToString();
            string s_interface = (info["InterfaceType"]==null? info["MediaType"].ToString():info["InterfaceType"].ToString());
            string s_serialnumber = (info["SerialNumber"] == null ? "No serial number": info["SerialNumber"].ToString()); 
            Global.LogMessage("Disk detected (Model: " + s_model + " | Interface: " + s_interface + " | Serial#: " + s_serialnumber,1);
            foreach (ManagementObject o in info.GetRelated("Win32_DiskPartition")) 
                foreach (ManagementObject i in o.GetRelated("Win32_LogicalDisk"))
                     s += i["Name"] + " ";
            Global.LogMessage("Logical disks: " + s,1);
        }
    }
```

The memory card doesn't seem to have a value for InterfaceType so I need to read MediaType instead. The same happens with the serial number, I don't know where to find it for a memory card.

Also, many values show its type (of value) in the value property such as

> [Capabilities] = 'System.UInt16[]'
>       -CIMTYPE- = 'uint16'

How can I get the real value of this property?

I admit I am a bit lost and diving in the official documentation is not an easy task... :/

Could anybody put some light ?

Thanks!
Jose

Comment: "with a type of value" that's not correct. `Capabilities` _is_ an `UInt16[]` array. The default `ToString()` method returns the type name, this is what you see. You could cast that property to `UInt16[]` and print out the values in the array (if that helps and you know how to interpret them).

Comment: I dont use ToString() to show the value of the property,  I use property.value. Using this, I see the right information for other properties like [MediaType] = 'Removable Media' - CIMTYPE- = 'string'. For some properties it has a real value for other contains its type. that is what  I dont really understand...

Comment: I don't know your `LogMessage` method, but I'm sure at some point you do something like `Console.WriteLine()` or a related call. These calls _do_ call `ToString()` if you pass non-string arguments. The `MediaType` is an enum, hence its value is printed out correctly. There is no default method that outputs the content of an array, `ToString()` _is called_ on that array and that outputs `System.UInt16[]`.

Comment: Ah, it doesn't depend on the `LogMessage` method, your concatenating strings. When you do `string s = "blah " + arrayVariable;`, then `ToString()` is called on `arrayVariable`.

Comment: Do you know a way to just print the value whichever the type is? so with a simple line I print in all cases? I am imaging the case statement depending of the value of the CIMTYPE and it looks too tedious but feasible. is that the way to go in your opinion?

Comment: and what about the serial number for memory cards? 
[SerialNumber] = ''  -CIMTYPE- = 'string'
do you know in which other property or place I could find it?

Answer (score 0):

After the good above suggestion from Rene, I tried to make it as dynamically as possible.
my goal is to cast the Property.value using the type from the value from the related QualifierData object.

My final working code is here. I am sure that there are more elegant ways to achieve it but this is the one I found. ;)

```
foreach (PropertyData property in properties){
foreach (QualifierData q in property.Qualifiers){
   if (property.IsArray){
       if (property.Value != null){
           Type t = property.Value.GetType();
           object o = property.Value;
           dynamic foo = o;
           if (IsPropertyExist(foo, "Length")){
                string s1 = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
                   s1 += "[" +foo[i] +"]";
                Global.LogMessage("[" + property.Name + "] (" + q.Value + ")  = " + s1 , 1);
        }
```